# Internationalization (i18n) for facelets images. Is it possible?

Tags: image, jsf-2, internationalization, facelets

Is it possible to internationalize facelets images? If so, how?
Do I make a bundle folder for it like for message bundles?
How does one configure it in the facelets-config.xml file (presuming it's possible). I am also open to trying icefaces, trinidad, rich faces provided that any of them make this functionality available. Although I am very unsure as to which of these is the best to use. I
am using Maven with both Nexus and JBoss repos ready find any needed plugins (I hope).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest would be to include the specific locale in the image's path or filename and making sure that those images exist for every supported locale. This way you could reference them as follows:

```
<h:graphicImage name="images/#{localeManager.language}/foo.png" />
```

*(which expects e.g. `images/en/foo.png`, `images/sp/foo.png`, etc)*

or

```
<h:graphicImage name="images/foo_#{localeManager.language}.png" />
```

*(which expects e.g. `images/foo_en.png`, `images/foo_sp.png`, etc)*

Or if you don't necessarily have a separate image for every locale and thus need to be able to have a fallback image for a locale which doesn't have a separate image, then the easiest would be to specify the image path/filename in the localized bundle file itself:

E.g. the default bundle:

```
images.foo = foo.png
```

and the locale-specific bundle which has the image:

```
images.foo = sp/foo.png 
# or foo_sp.png
```

and reference them as follows

```
<h:graphicImage name="images/#{bundle['images.foo']}" />
```